# Is the Taylor series of $f(x)= \sin x + \cos x$ just the sum of each individual Taylor series?

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I need to find the Taylor series for $f(x) = \sin x + \cos x$ centered at $0$ up to degree $3$. It's been a long time since the last time I did anything with the Taylor series.

So I was wondering if I could just add the Taylor series for $\sin x$ to the Taylor series of $\cos x$ to find the Taylor series for $\sin x + \cos x$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Intervals of convergence of $\sin x$, $\cos x$ and $\sin x+\cos x $ are all of real axis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just add the terms of each respective Taylor series together:

$$\sin x + \cos x \approx \left(x+\frac {x^3}{3!}\right)+\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}\right)$$

Since the two functions have an interval of convergence of all real numbers, term-by-term addition can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the radius of convergence the Taylor series is uniquely defined. Hence any (correct) technique for finding the coefficients will end up with the same result.

Another way would be
$f(x) = {1 \over 2i} (e^{ix}-e^{-ix}) + {1 \over 2} (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and then use
$e^{ix} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty i^n {x^n \over n!}$.

Then $f_n = {1 \over 2i} (i^n -(-i)^n ) + {1 \over 2} (i^n +(-i)^n)) {x^n \over n!}$ :-)

Note that ${1 \over 2i} (i^n -(-i)^n )$ has values $0, 1, 0, -1,...$,
and ${1 \over 2} (i^n +(-i)^n) $ has values $1, 0, -1, 0, ...$.